# Displayed URL does not match view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We are developing an MVC 4 application in C# (.NET 4.5, VS2012), and I have a navigation issue, where the controller (ReportsController.cs) explicitly names a view to return, as in:

```
return View("BeginDataExport", exList);
```

("exList" is the model.)  However, the URL displayed in the browser shows the previous view name, even though the view rendered is the desired one.  When the form posts, it posts to the wrong controller method.

If you explicitly name the view to return, as in this example, why does the URL show a different view name, even though the page displayed is the correct view?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Unless you have custom routing settings, url is in form `controller/action`, it does not reflect path to the view in any way. So if there are some problems with where the form post goes - it must be something inside the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Iif you want the URL to change, you need to use `return RedirectToAction()` (or another Redirect variation) and not `return View()`. As-is, the code is executing with the same route data (therefore no URL change), but you're just specifying which template to use.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the line in the view from `@using (Html.BeginForm())` to `@using (Html.BeginForm("BeginDataExport", "Reports"))` and now it works as desired.  The URL still displays the previous action.  Is this the correct way to solve this, when you want to return a different view, or should I use the `RedirectToAction()` method?

Comment: The URL is going to be retained so long as you don't go to another URL (i.e. return a `RedirectTo*` result). if you need the URL to change, the _easiest_ option is to redirect to that action.